# outlook 2010 virtual address book

Tags: outlook-addin, addressbook

I have contacts stored in a mySQL database, is it possible to create an add-in that presents a virtual address book with contact information that is retrieved from the database?  I don't want to do an import, I want the virtual address book to change as data in the contacts table changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to write a [custom address book provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb821134%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for Outlook. IIRC these have to be implemented in C++ due to MAPI requirements, but someone may have exposed these interfaces to languages like C# now.

Comment: I was hoping for a managed solution in C# but have opted to go for an import to a custom folder